# Check how many links I have in each page. Then placing that count at a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm doing this project to scrape how many links a series of webpages have.

My ideia is to add the count of the links for each page in a column of a Pandas dataframe. The ideia is to have something like this:

```
     title  count links
  0  page1  2
  1  page2  3
  2  page3  0
```

I did this code:

```
links_bs4 = ['page1', 'page2']
article_title = []
links = []

for item in links_bs4:
  page = requests.get(item)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  title = soup.find('title')
  article_title.append(title.string)
  body_text = soup.find('div', class_='article-body')
  for link in body_text.find_all('a'):
    links.append((link.get('href')))
    count_of_links = len(links)

s1 = pd.Series(article_title, name='title')
s2 = pd.Series(count_of_links, name='count links')
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

It partly works. The `count_of_links = len(links)` generates a count of all links of all pages combined.

I wish the count for each page, not the total as is happening now. How can I do this? My for loop is adding the count for the whole list. I should create a new list for each URL I scrape? Or use another thing in Python?

I'm clearly missing some part of the logic.

Comment: [You forgot to ask your qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @baduker sorry man, I thought I had. I updated the post. I wish the count for each page, not the total as is happening now. How can I do this? My for loop is adding the count for the whole list. I should create a new list for each URL I scrape? Or use another thing in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat `count_of_links` the same way as `article_title`. Below is based on your code, but with my changes.

```
links_bs4 = ['page1', 'page2']
article_title = []
count_of_links = [] # <------ added
links = []

for item in links_bs4:
  page = requests.get(item)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  title = soup.find('title')
  article_title.append(title.string)
  body_text = soup.find('div', class_='article-body')

  count = 0 # <------- added
  for link in body_text.find_all('a'):
    links.append((link.get('href')))
    # count_of_links = len(links) # <------- commented out
    count += 1 # <------- added
  count_of_links.append(count) # <------- added

s1 = pd.Series(article_title, name='title')
s2 = pd.Series(count_of_links, name='count links')
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

Or you may code it this way, then you won't need to create one variable for one new column, instead you only need to expand the dictionary.

```
links_bs4 = ['page1', 'page2']
data = []
links = []

for item in links_bs4:
  page = requests.get(item)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  title = soup.find('title')

  body_text = soup.find('div', class_='article-body')
  link_temp = [link.get('href') for link in body_text.find_all('a')]

  data.append({'title': title.string, 'count links': len(link_temp)})
  links.extend(link_temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Learned two things at once with your answer. Helped me a lot!